# dataframe.hist() with different bin size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, histogram

Need to plot Histogram with bin size of each column unique value.
Specially used when each column has unique value of totally diff size.

Suppose, one col has 2 unique values, bin = 2
another col has 50 unique values, bin = 50
Here, I cannot define a common bin size


I already tried:

```
dataframe.hist(bins = dataframe.nunique())
```

But this is not working.

Giving me this error:
ValueError: `bins` must increase monotonically, when an array

Comment: `dataframe['your_column'].value_counts().plot.bar()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That's the thing, I want to do for all the columns in one go. What if I have 20 columns.

Comment: `dataframe.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().plot.bar())`? Or even `for column in df.columns: do_the_previous_comment`?

Comment: @QuangHoang umm. It should work, but my jupyter notebook is giving me just one plot. I believe, it is nt showing each one.

Comment: you can create a new figure instance within the for loop. Let me put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    df[col].value_counts().plot.bar(ax=ax)
```